# Protractor with typescript and mocha framework and chai assertions i get error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded

Tags: typescript, protractor, mocha.js, chai

I am not able to execute a simple test in protractor with mocha, typescript and chai.
I get the below error:
*"Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves."*

After the browser.get() line is executed, the page opens and closes abruptly with the above error. I do not have any other line executing after this, as i wanted this to be executed first successfully.

I have tried to put browser.sleep() as well, no luck.
I have tried all options mentioned in all similar issues (different timeouts here and there) none works.
My package.json has:
Protractor version : 7.0.0,
Mocha: 8.1.3,
typescript: 3.4.3,
jasmine:3.6.1,
@types/.. all latest versions,
chai and chai-as-promised

I am also using async/await.

I am stuck with this for more than 2 weeks now. Please help with ideas.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please post your test code. But if you "do not have any other line executing" maybe this is the error, you need to cal `done()`. But, share your code to get a better know about the problem.

Comment: Hello J.F, thanks for the response. I studied and it seems i need to put my mochaopts under test folder for it to recognize, not sure though, but will try it tomorrow and give a response here, as my vm got stuck. else will post code. Also i tried with done options as well, none worked.

Answer (score 0):

Got my vm today, and found out that **mochaOpts** was spelled wrong in my config, it was spelt as **mochaopts**, which was the issue, because of which timeout was not getting considered. After i changed the spelling, timeout error didnt come and test passed.
thought of sharing it, as we might end up doing this unknowingly.

thank you!!!!
have a good learning.